# No column "flaggings_count" using make_flaggable with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlexception

I'm working on a Rails 4 app, and installed the make_flaggable gem (following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GG-kCSx0taU)) to allow users to like posts. Whenever I try to make a user like a post (on the browser or console), it keeps showing me this error :

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: flaggings_count: UPDATE "posts" SET "flaggings_count" = COALESCE("flaggings_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "posts"."id" = 67

Here's my like method :

```
def like
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  current_user.flag(@post, :like)
  redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "You now like this post"
end
```

The migration looks ok, did it happen to anyone? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is using a counter_cache with flaggings_count.

Do a migration and add a flaggings_count column to your posts table.

```
def change
  add_column :post, :flaggings_count, :integer
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to do the same for the users table